# PHP url decoding or encoding help needed

Tags: php

Hey I'm trying to pass variables to my variation product page.

For example, im able to pass the keys and part numbers via

http://comugg.com/product/generallisting6/?attribute_pa_keys=yes&attribute_pa_part-number=0-261-204-591

however when i try to pass the engine size using the same format...for example,

http://comugg.com/product/generallisting6/?attribute_pa_engine-size=1.8L

it doesnt work. im assuming its becuase of the "." im wondering what i can do?

P.S. ive already tried using the slug 1-6L. it doesnt work:(

Comment: Change it to something else any other special caracter like "!"

Comment: A `.` in a URL shouldn't be a special character needing escaping. Can you show us the PHP code involved?

Comment: im using woo commerce. im unsure of what needs to be shown?

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldnt `attribute_pa_engine-size=1.8L` be `attribute_pa_engine_size=1.8L` ? a `.` does not have any influence here. Simplest way to check is to simply dump out `$_GET` and see what fields and what values you have there

Comment: Auris ive tried your suggestion and it doesnt work. that $-get idea is great ill give it a try.

Comment: One more thing, normally a `.` does not have any influence in a query string but if your app uses htaccess some poorely written  regex in there may produce unexpected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the value and name should be same for this to work.
Try http://comugg.com/product/generallisting6/?attribute_pa_engine-size=1-6L. 
Working fine if the value and name are same. try using same for 1.8L.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in the URL don't like dots I'm afraid.

Why not use the following when creating the variable and then reverse when reading?

```
$variablename = str_replace(".","_",$variablename;
```